# Python chatbot not working properly

Tags: python, nltk, chatbot

I'm working on a chatbot which has two scenarios.

**1:** When the user types a question, if that question is available it training dataset, It picks a response for that question from the training dataset.

**2:** If the question typed by user is not available in the dataset, system gives response from default answers which are defined with in the code.

My problem is, when the system gets a question statement that is not in the training data, it picks a random answer from the code (Fine). But from that point, it starts giving default answers no matter which question we ask. It never picks an answer from training data despite having that particular question and its answer in the training data.

The entire code is too large to paste here. I'm writing just those functions where the problem occurs. Hope someone could help me with this.

```
def response(sentence, userID='123', show_details=False):
    results = classify(sentence)
    # if we have a classification then find the matching intent tag
    if results:
        # loop as long as there are matches to process
        while results:
            #some if else statements to match the question
            results.pop(0)
        while not results:
            pairs = (
                (r'I need (.*)',
                 ("Why do you need %1?",
                  "Would it really help you to get %1?",
                  "Are you sure you need %1?")),

                (r'Why don\'t you (.*)',
                 ("Do you really think I don't %1?",
                  "Perhaps eventually I will %1.",
                  "Do you really want me to %1?"))

            )

            aida_chatbot = Chat(pairs, reflections)

            def aida_chat():
                aida_chatbot.converse()

            def demo():
                aida_chat()

            if __name__ == "__main__":
                demo()
            else:
                response()
                # sentence = sys.stdin.readline()
    sys.stdout.write("> ")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    classify(sentence=sys.stdin.readline())
    while True:
        response(sentence=sys.stdin.readline())
```

When I put the **pairs** outside the while statement, (e.g in else statement after the if statement is closed), program never enters the else statement and this part of code is never executed.
Cany anybody help me with this?

Comment: Your problem is within your loops. Your else statement in the "while not results" fires off another empty call to response

Comment: Please edit your question and indent your code to match your actual program. The line after `aida_chatbot = Chat(...` is an indentation syntax error, so your program certainly doesn't look like that.

Comment: @alexis done. Now what?

Comment: @zerohero can you identify it in a more easy way please? I did not get it. :-(

Comment: @Tauseef, now wait for more answers. But the list `pairs`, the chatbot and the function definitions are invariant in your program, there's no reason to redefine them every time you go through the loop.

Comment: I recommend untangling your code. `response()` defines other functions, calls itself, checks if it's being run in `__main__`, provides a demo mode, ... It's a mess, and this doesn't even count the code you left out. Write minimal code that only does what you describe in your question, and you'll be in a better position to debug it.

Comment: @Tauseef_Ahmed see added answer by P.Madhukar. If you can't identify it from my description, then I suggest refactoring your code and logic to simplify it

Answer (score 1):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo()
else:
    response()
```

You are not passing question text from this response function call. Just pass your question as an argument from this response function call.

Comment: @P.Mdhakar I'll try your solution. Thanks